# Storing most frequently used values in an array from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What I'm basically trying to do is get the top 3 most frequent values from a column in my database, I have searched for a solution but couldn't find anything. I already have the code to get the most frequently used;

```
 $mostFrequentUser = $db->query("SELECT emailFrom FROM details group by emailFROM having count(*) = (SELECT count (*) FROM details group by emailFrom ORDER BY count(*) desc LIMIT 1)");
 $frequent = $mostFrequentUser->fetchColumn();
```

It's so I can order them from 1 - 3 of who uses the system the most and display it on a webpage, any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: have you tried changing your limit from 1 to 3?

Comment: @Rob How do I get the 3 most frequent values from a column in my database and store them in an array...

Comment: I have added the MySQL tag since your goal will best be accomplished by crafting the right query.

Comment: @Jim if I change it to 3 then it will display the same value 3 times due to it being 'most frequently used'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT emailFrom 
FROM (
    SELECT emailFrom, COUNT(emailFrom) AS myCount
    FROM details
    GROUP BY emailFROM 
    ORDER BY myCount DESC
    LIMIT 3
    ) temp
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object

Comment: Ah, forgot the FROM clause in inner query @user2406160

Comment: Ahh you legend! thank you very much that has fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only fetching the column for the first result. You want to use `fetchAll()` or iterate through the cursor.

`$frequent = $mostFrequentUser->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Also change your limit from 1 to 3 as stated above.

Comment: Now it brings it back like this ["value"] and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Do a group by (just like you did), alias the count to "n" and then wrap the select inside another select where you order by n. Then fetch the first three values.

Comment: I don't want to fetch the first 3 values only I want to select the 3 most frequently used values... if I select the first 3 values then they will all be the same

Comment: See hjpotter92's answer. It is what I meant